# How do I report a suspicious snap on the store?

Tags: security, bug-reporting, snap

I installed a snap from the store using `snap find` and `snap install`. After installing it I noticed that it behaves suspiciously. How do I report this?

Comment: [http://snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io/) ?

Comment: I filed a bug to help track this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1615842

Answer (score 4):

Alan & co will ensure there is a public mechanism for this. In the meanwhile, for this specific case, can I suggest an off-list email to any of the long-standing Ubuntu folks who can address a specific snap.